# Issue in httpost app stops

Tags: android

so, i have this code here:
This doesn't really work , i get app has stopped, the issue is, before when i tried this at home it worked just fine...now it doesn't! 
I don't know what is wrong here, could someone please take a look and tell me?
Thanks..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText msgTextField;
    Button sendButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //make message text field object
            msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
            //make button object
            sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        }

        public void send(View v)
        {
            //get message from message box
            String  msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();

            //check whether the msg empty or not
            if(msg.length()>0) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.28/app/app1.php");

                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
                       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                       httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        msgTextField.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                //display message if text field is empty
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All fields are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Here i have the Manifes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.form"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.form.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some stuff that musn't be called from the UI Thread. You can create an AsyncTask to do such operations. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) for more infos.

Comment: I am very new to this.. coudl you please help me implement it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Every blocking calls have to run on a thread different from the `UI Thread`. You are getting the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Use a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`.  Read [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/05/painless-threading.html)